# How to parse and get data from webservice which is returning a list of array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi Every one I am trying to get data from webservice which is returning me XML.I used the Xml to JSON dependency to return me data in JSON but another problem is it is returning me the data in an array  and the app cant display the data.But it comes out in the terminal  just fine

Here is the image

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Source extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Source Listing',
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
      headerTitleStyle: { textAlign: 'center', flex: 1 },
    });

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        dataSource: [],
      };
    }

    FlatListItemSeparator = () => (
      <View style={{
        height: 0.5,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
      }}/>
    )

    renderItem=data => <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
        <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.email}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.company.name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
        <View style={styles.loader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
        </View>
        );
      }
      return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
        data= {this.state.dataSource}
        ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
        renderItem= {item => this.renderItem(item)}
        keyExtractor= {item => item.id.toString()}
     />
    </View>
      );
    }
}
const { parseString } = require('react-native-xml2js');

fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((response) => {
    parseString(response, (err, result) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('fetch', err);
  });

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  loader: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  list: {
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Is there any way i can display the data in the app as single string entity

Comment: Can you show us how result in console.log(response) after parsing ?

Comment: Sure I will edit the question and put image on it

Comment: you should destruct `item`, `renderItem= {({item})=> ...`

Comment: Also you should make the fetching in componentDidMount, it could be more easier to manipulate data within lifecycle of component

Comment: @Salim Sorry that did not solve my problem

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui have you try Hagai Harari's solution ?

Comment: @Salim Yes did try it